# how to use map function in a list using Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my HTMl,

```html
<div id="container" class="myGal" tabindex="5001" style="overflow: hidden; outline: none;">
   <select id="Select1" style="display:none" multiple="multiple" data-limit="7" wtx-context="5C3D486B-FBBF-4191-BDA3-C2F28323036B">
      <option></option>
      <option data-img-src="" value="728" data-img-label="10"></option>
      <option data-img-src="" data-img-label="11"></option>
      <option data-img-src="" value="730" data-img-label="12"></option>
   </select>
   <ul class="thumbnails image_picker_selector">
      <li>
         <div class="thumbnail selected"><img class="image_picker_image loaded" src="http://localhost:1344//ARTSQLDATA/PTDIR/170629062/Pictures/Personal_Picture/170629062_4353_4a97162c-7350-43eb-82df-6e92f49b30bb.jpg?w=90&amp;h=90&amp;mode=max"></div>
      </li>
      <li>
         <div class="thumbnail"><img class="image_picker_image loaded" src="http://localhost:1344//ARTSQLDATA/PTDIR/170629062/Pictures/Personal_Picture/170629062_4353_bb197250-91ab-449e-9cd0-3f69ef3a7353.jpg?w=90&amp;h=90&amp;mode=max"></div>
      </li>
      <li>
         <div class="thumbnail selected"><img class="image_picker_image" src="http://localhost:1344//ARTSQLDATA/PTDIR/170629062/Pictures/Personal_Picture/170629062_4353_8eb91587-f229-46f4-af1e-7327cb81a25e.jpg?w=90&amp;h=90&amp;mode=max"></div>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

has a `select` control that has a list associated to it. I want to map and get all image sources that has `thumbnail selected` class

I tried this but i get an empty array,

```
var list = $('.thumbnail').map(function () { return $(this).closest("img").attr("src"); }).get();

console.log(list.join(','))
```

Comment: You could have included line breaks in your code for easier reading.

Comment: I will add it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do `children()` instead of `closest()` (***Because `images` are `children` of `thumbnail` divs***):-

```js
var list = $('.thumbnail').map(function () { return $(this).children("img").attr("src"); }).get();

console.log(list);

//console.log(list.join(','));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" class="myGal" tabindex="5001" style="overflow: hidden; outline: none;">
  <select id="Select1" style="display:none" multiple="multiple" data-limit="7" wtx-context="5C3D486B-FBBF-4191-BDA3-C2F28323036B">
    <option></option>
    <option data-img-src="" value="728" data-img-label="10"></option>
    <option data-img-src="" data-img-label="11"></option><option data-img-src="" value="730" data-img-label="12"></option>
  </select>
  <ul class="thumbnails image_picker_selector">
    <li>
      <div class="thumbnail selected">
        <img class="image_picker_image loaded" src="http://localhost:1344//ARTSQLDATA/PTDIR/170629062/Pictures/Personal_Picture/170629062_4353_4a97162c-7350-43eb-82df-6e92f49b30bb.jpg?w=90&amp;h=90&amp;mode=max">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="image_picker_image loaded" src="http://localhost:1344//ARTSQLDATA/PTDIR/170629062/Pictures/Personal_Picture/170629062_4353_bb197250-91ab-449e-9cd0-3f69ef3a7353.jpg?w=90&amp;h=90&amp;mode=max">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="thumbnail selected">
        <img class="image_picker_image" src="http://localhost:1344//ARTSQLDATA/PTDIR/170629062/Pictures/Personal_Picture/170629062_4353_8eb91587-f229-46f4-af1e-7327cb81a25e.jpg?w=90&amp;h=90&amp;mode=max">
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Note:- `closest()` use to check elements on same-level, but here images are children of the corresponding div, that's why you are getting empty array.

Answer (score 2):

One of the simplest thing to do is put your criteria directly in jquery selector and select the image elements and process them. Here is the JS code.

```
$('.thumbnail.selected > img').map(function() {return this.src;}).get().join(',');
```